# django does not match pattern called in template

Tags: python, regex, django, django-templates, django-urls

Iam trying to call `{% url %}` in a template to have dynamic links, but i get an error although the pattern should match. Here are my files:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<team_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

template file

```
{% for team in teams_list %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'detail' team.id %}/">{{ team.name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
def detail(request, team_id):
    team = get_object_or_404(Team, id=team_id)
    context = {
        'teamname' : team.name,
        'member_list' : User.objects.filter(team__name=team.name)
    }
    return render(request, 'teams/detail.html', context)
```

I tried it doing analog to the django tutorial, but i can't seem to find my error. the error statement is the following:

```
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clue is in the error message, specifically ***and keyword arguments '{}' not found.***.

Your pattern has keyword matching, the result will be mapped to the keyword `team_id`, however you are passing a *positional argument* of `1` (that's why your team id is showing in the tuple `(1,)`).

To fix this, change your url tag to `{% url 'detail' team_id=team.id %}`.

You can read more about this at the [`url` tag documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

Comment: Thank you very much, your help and further resources are appreciated.

Comment: I've never had any issues providing a tuple of arguments to `reverse` when the pattern has keyword arguments. The `0 pattern(s) tried` looks more suspect to me.